# Error passing InputStream through multiple Jersey-Client requests

Tags: jersey-client

I’m using jersey-client v1.18.1

I need to make 2 sequential requests where the 1st request has an InputStream and then must pass that same **InputStream** along to the 2nd request (eg. sort of like a proxy).  The 2nd request will then write the InputStream to disk and send back to the 1st request the fully qualified path to the location on disk where the 2nd request wrote the file.

The following code-snippet outlines what I have tried, but cannot get to work properly. I’m currently receiving the error:

"com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpInputOverHTTP, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found”

I believe I have all the proper Maven dependencies in my project for the MIME and message body writers.

**1st Request originating on Host 1 going to Host 2**

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.resource(uri_for_request_1)
client.path(“request_1_servlet");
client.queryParam(“uri_for_request_2", uri_for_request_2);
client.queryParam("targetFilename", targetFilename);
ClientResponse response = client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(inputStream).post(ClientResponse.class);
```

**2nd Request originating on Host 2 going to Host 3**

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.resource(request.getParamater(“uri_for_request_2"))
client.path(“request_2_servlet");
client.queryParam("targetFilename", request.getParamater(“targetFilename");
ClientResponse response = client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(request.getInputStream()).post(ClientResponse.class);
```

**Host 3**
Writes InputStream to file and sends back to Host 2 fully qualified path.

**Host 2**
Sends back to Host 1 fully qualified path.

**Variations I’ve tried on post calls:**
client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).entity(inputStream).post(ClientResponse.class);
client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).post(ClientResponse.class, inputStream);

I can confirm the 1st request is being made on Host 1 and reaches Host 2. It is the 2nd request on Host 2 that fails during the post() call.